# Не работает css в классах div и id

Tags: html, css

У меня такая проблема:
Все работало отлично, но в один момент перестали работать стили для любых созданных div классов и div id. Что я делаю не так, и как это исправить?

```css
body{
 background: green;
}

p{
 font-size: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 color: yellow;
}

header{
 font-size: 100px;
 background: #CC0000;
 height: 300px;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <p>Жуйка</p>
 <div class="header">
  Текст
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работаю в Sublime Text 3
Валидатор ошибок не нашел

Comment: в css не `header`, а `.header`

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Я понял в чем проблема. По не внимательности обращался к тегу а не к классу.
Перед `header{…}` нужна точка `.header{…}`